# How to set error reporting dynamically in PHP

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am trying to dynamically set error reporting in PHP but I can't get the syntax right.

I tried :

```
ini_set('error_reporting',0);
```

and than this:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

But both are unable to stop the error reporting. Kindly tell me what mistake I am doing? Thank you.

(I am new to PHP and using [this resource](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=11) to learn PHP.)

EDIT: The Entire code is :

```
<?php

    ini_set('error_reporting',0);
    echo "hello world"
    $value = "abc";
    ?>
    <input type = "text" value = "<?php echo $value;?>">
```

I intentionally made a mistake in second line to study the error.

Comment: The syntax is right . Where did you put the code?

Comment: I am using the XAMPP server in my Desktop and its not working. and even in the tutorial video the syntax is not working . Here is the video : http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=15

Comment: In my php.ini it is set as E_ALL. Is the INI file supersedes the source file?

Comment: No, the source file supersedes the ini file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have "PHP Parse error" and it means PHP cannot compile your code, thus your error reporting setting will not work.

Try this:

```
error_reporting(0);
echo $foo; // This line produces notice about unset variable, but it is suppressed by error reporting level 0
```

Comment: ok. Means since my code can not be compiled. Therefor PHP is using setting from INI file.

Answer (score 1):

It is a syntax error. Hence no lines will be executed, so you cannot use `ini_set` or `error_reporting`.

If you are using Apache + mod_php, use `.htaccess` to suppress error reporting.

```
php_value error_reporting 0
php_flag display_errors off
```

In case you are using php cgi or fcgi, use a custom php.ini file.

Comment: Don't use .htaccess as it's runtime config.